# In the Info.plist, <string></string>

Tags: ios, xml, info.plist

I added the following text to the Info.plist in an attempt to implement biometric authentication:

```
<key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
```

However, I encountered an error. So I made the following modification:

```
<key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
<string>Why is my app authenticating using face id?</string>  /* add */
```

Why is the text enclosed in `<string></string>` necessary?

Comment: There's no need to manually edit Info.plist. Go to the Info tag of your target and add the appropriate privacy setting and value. This ensures you don't make a typo or leave out the proper XML syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `plist` file is a file that contains key-value pairs. Each system key has a different purpose. *i.e.* `UIMainStoryboardFile` determines the `main.storyboard`, *etc.* In your case, it's for a permission request, specially biometric. You have to provide a value for this key which will show up as a message on the permission alert. Check this document below:

> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW75

[image]